# How can I write a commit hash to a file using .gitlab-ci before build and deploy

Tags: gitlab-ci

I want to add an endpoint in my server to retrieve the current commit hash in production. I am using `.gitlab-ci`. I want to do this in the pipeline so that the commit hash is written to a file before "build and deploy". I can read this file on request to return the latest deployed version. Can anyone help me with the steps and examples? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would offer an alternative to this. Use GitLab's [environments and deployments](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/) features that, in part, considers this exact use case.

In your CI/CD configuration (`.gitlab-ci.yml`), you can specify an `environment:` key that will record deployments to your environment(s).

For example:

```yaml
deploy:
  script:
    - echo "your deployment script here"
  environment:
    name: "production"
```

Now, when this job runs, GitLab will record it as a deployment that can be queried later.

Then you can use the [deployments API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/deployments.html) or the [environments API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/environments.html) to get the latest deployment information which will include, among other information, the commit hash of the deployment.

Comment: Hey @sytech, thank you for the quick response. Based on the sample script you added, should the script look like this?
`script:`
   `- echo $CI_COMMIT_SHA`